# Records not shown while selecting from table in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm Getting total tables in whole database and its row-count from following query:

```
  SELECT  SCHEMA_NAME(A.schema_id) + '.' +
            A.Name, SUM(B.rows) AS 'RowCount'
    FROM        sys.objects A
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions B ON A.object_id = B.object_id
    WHERE       A.type = 'U'
    GROUP BY    A.schema_id, A.Name
    Order By 'RowCount' desc
```

After that i'm getting below result:

[image]

And then finally when i'm trying to fetch records from one of this table

`select * from dbo.[xxx_$Retail ICT Header]`

It gives 0 rows as output......Any clue?

Comment: well your table name is [Ltd_$Retail ICT Header] not [xxx_$Retail ICT Header] by the looks of it.

Comment: @Rich Benner :yes sir I know it...but for security purpose i write here xxx ! !

Comment: Well that's daft. You've shown us your table name in the picture. There's no reason why your final query shouldn't work as long as you have the table name correct. Also, check that you're connected to the correct database in SSMS, you're not still connected to master are you?

Comment: Did you checked whether that table is locked? try once SELECT * FROM TableName WITH (NOLOCK)

Comment: @RichBenner: Sir I write table-name in query right and when I'm trying to fetch from other tables i got output as expected as row-count .But not for 4-5 tables.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? And you're absolutely sure that you don't have anything wrong in your table name? Try adding your database and schema name to the query (e.g. SELECT * FROM databasename.dbo.tablename) to see if that sorts it.

Comment: @RichBenner yes sir my whole query is fine also tried database and schema name in it. But not working. Now tryng to check whether there is lock or not for this tables ! and No error messages !

Comment: Then speak to your DBA because you have something else wrong somewhere with your system.

Comment: @RichBenner : SIr we dont have any DBA ....Our company is Startup !

Comment: @Srinath: Sir Dont get any result ! !

Comment: @dev.Sumit There's something going on that is going to be very difficult for us to diagnose. Have you considered the "nuke it from orbit" approach and restarting your SQL Server?

Comment: why are you using '$'  in table names?

Comment: @mcNets I dont know sir !

Answer (score 0):

To get the Row count in each table try below query and after that cross check by running select query.

```
SELECT s.name+'.'+o.name,
  ddps.row_count 
FROM sys.indexes AS i  
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON i.OBJECT_ID = o.OBJECT_ID
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on s.schema_id= o.schema_id
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ddps ON i.OBJECT_ID = ddps.OBJECT_ID
  AND i.index_id = ddps.index_id 
WHERE i.index_id < 2  AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0 ORDER BY o.NAME
```

Comment: same problem. I think there should be lock in that table ! But how do i check if table is locked or not ?

Comment: After running the above query, what is the row count of your table name? Is it greater than zero? Did you checked this?@dev.Sumit

Comment: Yes @Srinath sir I checked it and rowcount is greater than zero. SO what do you think ?? Is it some kind of protection for that table ???